# Indy TIdFTP "Out of Memory" error when downloading a large file

Tags: delphi, indy10

I am using `TIdFTP` (Indy 10.6) to upload a large file that exceeds 1GB.

When I want to download that file, I get an error message saying "Out of Memory".

Here is my code:

```pascal
var
  FTPfile: TMemoryStream;
begin
  ...
  FTPFile := TMemoryStream.Create;
  ...
  TRY
    IdFTP1.Get ('Myfile.pdf', FTPfile, false);
    FTPfile.Position := 0;
  EXCEPT
    On E: Exception do
      ShowMessage (E.Message);
  END;
```

I am using a 32bit version of Windows.

Is there a solution to work around this problem?

Comment: Your are loading the file into memory (which is limited as you found out), you can easily solve this problem by loading the file onto disk by using a TFilestream.

Comment: thank you for your help.

Comment: Also, you should get rid of the `try..except`. You get a message box with the exception even without this block. And this block does harm: it will let the routine continue after the exception, which will likely lead to even more problems. Instead, use a `try..finally` to protect the stream object.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to download a **1GB** file into a `TMemoryStream`.  Aside from just being a bad idea in general, the main problem with doing this is that the FTP protocol does not report the size of a file that is being transferred, so `TIdFTP.Get()` can't pre-allocate the `TMemoryStream`'s internal buffer up front.  As such, as the file downloads, the `TMemoryStream.Capacity` will have to grow many times, and each time it will allocate a completely new buffer, copy the existing data into it, and free the old buffer.  This means that during a growth operation, there is a small window of time where 2 buffers exist in memory.  So you are actually using much more memory than you think.  And storing a 1GB file in memory is really pushing the limit of how much memory a 32bit process can even allocate.

Eventually, the `TMemoryStream` will grow so large that the system just can't allocate that 2nd buffer anymore, thus failing with the "Out of Memory" error.

You could try using `TIdFTP.Size()` or `TIdFTP.List()` to determine the remote file's size ahead of time, set the `TMemoryStream.Capacity` accordingly, and then call `TIdFTP.Get()`.  This way, there is only 1 memory allocation performed.

Also, make sure you `Free()` the `TMemoryStream` when you are done using it, or else you will leak whatever memory it was able to allocate.

But really, you should download the file to disk instead.  You can use a `TFileStream` for that, but `TIdFTP.Get()` has an overload that takes a local file path as the destination instead of a `TStream`.

If you need to access the file's data in memory, you can read/memory-map it as needed after the download is complete.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So Remy, are you suggesting that I use TFileStream?

Comment: @Amélie Yes.  Which the other overload of `TIdFTP.Get()` already handles for you.

Comment: @ Remy: I am having difficulty in managing the opening of the file. The file is downloaded to disk but I get an error message telling me that the file cannot be created or opened because it is in use by another process. I have some bad handling in my code.
What code are you using to do this with "TFileStream"?

Comment: @Amélie sounds like you are not `Free`ing the `TFileStream` when you are done using it. Just like with your `TMemoryStream`. As I said earlier, you should use the 2nd overload of `TIdFTP.Get()` that takes a destination file path rather than a `TStream`, let it handle its own stream internally.

Comment: is it like that please?     `FichierFTP := TFileStream.Create(PChar(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\Temps\' + 'MyFile.pdf') , fmCreate );    TRY
Form1.IdFTP1.Get(DBEditNomFichierHDD.Text ,PChar(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\Temps\' + DBEditNomFichierHDD.Text)  , true  ); 
FichierFTP.Position:= 0 ; 
except  
  On E:Exception do  
 // ShowMessage(E.Message);
 ShowMessage('Ce fichier est introuvable sur le serveur');
END;   FichierFTP.Free; `

Comment: @Amélie If you pass in a destination filename, DON'T create the `TFileStream` at all. Use EITHER a stream OR a filename, NOT both. `FichierFTP := TFileStream.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\Temps\'+'MyFile.pdf', fmCreate); try IdFTP1.Get ('Myfile.pdf', FichierFTP, false); finally FichierFTP.Free; end` Or just `IdFTP1.Get ('Myfile.pdf', ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\Temps\'+'MyFile.pdf', false);` by itself

Comment: Thank your your help. I didn't use `TFileStream`, just an   `IdFTP1.Get`